# Convenience initialiser keeps crashing however designated initialiser works fine?

Tags: swift, initialization, init, swift-playground, convenience-methods

When creating an instance using the convenience initialiser the playground keeps giving me this error "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee5ae9ff8)" however when using the designated initialiser it works fine.

I'm not entirely sure if i'm setting the convenience initialiser correctly so that only the arsenal parameter is required when creating a new instance.

```
class FootballTeams {

 var liverpool: String
 var chelsea: String
 var manchesterunited: String
 var arsenal: String = "fourth"

 init(arsenal:String, chelsea:String,     
      liverpool: String, manchesterunited:String ) { //designated initialiser
    self.arsenal = arsenal
    self.chelsea = chelsea
    self.liverpool = liverpool
    self.manchesterunited = manchesterunited
}

 convenience init(arsenal: String){
    self.init(arsenal: arsenal) //call to designated initialiser   above
    self.arsenal = arsenal
}
}

let properInstance = FootballTeams(arsenal: "Overides stored  property value", chelsea: "a", liverpool: "b", manchesterunited: "b")
print(properInstance.arsenal)

let convenienceInstance = FootballTeams(arsenal: "This is an instance from the convenience init")
print(convenienceInstance.arsenal)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into an infinite loop, didn't you see the warning

> All paths through this function will call itself

That means `init(arsenal` calls `init(arsenal` which calls `init(arsenal` which calls `init(arsenal` which calls `init(arsenal` which ...

To call the convenience initializer you have to call the designated initializer and provide default values

```
convenience init(arsenal: String) {
    self.init(arsenal: arsenal, chelsea:"sixth", liverpool: "first", manchesterunited: "fifth") //call to designated initialiser   above
}
```

The extra line `self.arsenal = arsenal` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I'm still new to Swift this really helps, is there a way in a convenience init can use the designated initialisers default values? Rather than providing default ones as you described above

Comment: Except `arsenal` there are no default values. A default value must be assigned in the declaration line.

Comment: ‍♂️ Thanks again! I understand where I was going wrong

Comment: And please conform to the naming convention that struct and class names start with a capital letter.